# Pre Select Rows in Lightning Data Table

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I want to Preselect all data in my Lightning Data Table. for that, I have added selected-rows also. But not working. My code

```
<lightning-datatable 
    data={data}
    selected-rows={data}
    columns={columns}
    key-field="Id"
    column-widths-mode="auto"
    > 
</lightning-datatable>
```

Note: I want to pre-select all the displayed data hence used **data** in both data and selected-rows.

Thanks
Nirav

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`selected-rows` should be bound to a list of key-field values (Ids, in this case), not to a list of records

> Enables programmatic row selection with a list of key-field values.

per the [LWC Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/specification).

You'd need in your component to create a new field to store the selected Ids, and prepopulate it at load time with the Ids of all of your records. Then, bind `selected-rows` to that field.

Comment: could you elaborate a little more on that? how would my data array have to look like here?

Answer (score 0):

```
var preSelectedRows= [];
var myId = '#the Id#';
preSelectedRows.push(myId);
```

then update attribute used in your table:

```
cmp.set('v.preSelectedRows', preSelectedRows);
```